# The word Apikores

Tags: words

The Word אפיקרסין is mentioned in Yerushalmi Brachos (14-in old prints) to mean a robe. Also in Maseches Avel Rabasi perek 9 and 22. Also in Maseches tzitzis perek aleph.

This word is strikingly similar to the word אפיקורוס found in Mishna Sanhedrin 99

Is there any connection between these words?

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%DC%90%DC%A6%DC%A9%DC%AA%DC%A3%DC%90

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/apikoros#:~:text=Etymology,%2C%20%E2%80%9Cto%20abandon%E2%80%9D).

Comment: not seeing an answer to my question as to if these 2 words are connected

Answer (score 1):

The words are not directly related. Jastrow thinks they share a common root, but that seems dubious. According to Jastrow they both from from the root P-Q-R meaning to undo or break free. He ties "apikoros" in the sense of a heretic to the word אַפְקָרוּתָא, commonly used to mean licentiousness or irreverence. See Jastrow אַפְקָרוּתָא. See also Moed Katan 16 for that shoresh is used in multiple related ways. The word אַפִּיקַרְסִין, and many variations, is pretty common in the talmudim and midrashim and refers to some kind of garment, possibly a robe, turban, or undergarment. Jastrow thinks the primary meaning is undergarment, which he connects to the same root of P-Q-R (i.e., it's what's left when you are undressed). https://www.sefaria.org/Jastrow%2C_%D7%90%D6%B7%D7%A4%D6%B0%D7%A7%D6%B7%D7%A8%D6%B0%D7%A1%D6%B4%D7%99%D7%9F.1?lang=bi

The dominant view is that apikoros/epikoros (as in a heretic) comes from the name of the Greek philosopher Epicurus, though there may be some word play with *afkaruta* as well. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epikoros. The shoresh of *apikarsin* etc. is unknown, though if it is related to the Syriac word identified by Kazi bacsi, Wiktionary suggests a different Greek root. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%DC%90%DC%A6%DC%A9%DC%AA%DC%A3%DC%90